# how to fix tensorflow & keras shape error?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, ocr

I am trying to train custom OCR model. When training with my own data compared to the data provide in [this tutorial](https://keras.io/examples/vision/captcha_ocr/), it seems to break with error message:

```
Local rendezvous is aborting with status: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of elements does not match. Shapes are: [tensor]: [4], [batch]: [3]
```

I tried researching, but I can not find any information regarding this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. I think it was a issue of image dimensions I had to change (or perhaps some text length value)? The width and height had to match input image.